# pythonでクラスを継承して__init__をオーバーライドしつつ、自分自身を更新したい

Tags: python, class

pythonで以下のようにDataFrameを継承して新しいクラスを作ります。このとき`__init__`をオーバーライドして、nanを除去する処理を加えたいです。しかし、`dropna`は返り値として新たなDataFrameオブジェクトを返すため、コメントアウトした部分を加えても`ndf`はnanを含んだままです。
どのようにすればいいでしょうか？このように既存のクラスを継承する場合の最も一般的な方法が知りたいです。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
class NewDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #super().dropna(how = 'any')

ndf = NewDataFrame([[1, 2], [3, np.nan]])
print(ndf)
```

Comment: パラメータに`inplace=True`を設定してみてはどうでしょう？ [pandas.DataFrame.dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

Comment: コメントアウトされている部分の `super().dropna(how = 'any')` ですが、そこは `self.dropna(how = 'any', inplace = True)` でよいかと。(`super().__init__()` の後なので)

Comment: ありがとうございます。たしかにこれでできそうです。一般的に既存のクラスのメソッドが新たなオブジェクトを返すものであるが、それと同様の処理を自身のインスタンス変数を書き換え実現したい場合どうすればいいのでしょうか？メソッドのソースコードを確認する必要があるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

思いついた方法をいくつか並べておきます。

一つ目は、返された新たなDataFrameオブジェクトをコンストラクタに渡して初期化する方法。

```python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
class NewDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(pd.DataFrame(*args, **kwargs).dropna(how = 'any'))

ndf = NewDataFrame([[1, 2], [3, np.nan]])
print(ndf)
```

もう一つは、返された新たなDataFrameオブジェクトの`__class__`を無理やり書き換えて、サブクラスのオブジェクトにしてしまう方法。`__init__`を空にしないと、改めて初期化されて上書きされてしまうので注意が必要です。

```python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
class NewDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = pd.DataFrame(*args, **kwargs).dropna(how = 'any')
        obj.__class__ = cls
        return obj
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

ndf = NewDataFrame([[1, 2], [3, np.nan]])
print(ndf)
```

個人的な感想ですが、このようなクラスを作っても、新たなオブジェクトを生成するメソッドを呼ぶと`DataFrame`に戻ってしまうので、わざわざ専用のクラスを作る意義を感じません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。